# Obtaining a Reference do the Script's Parent Element

Tags: ajax, dom

I am using AJAX to return a response which includes a script.

Through that script, how can I determine the ID of the parent element the script is running in without passing id's to the server?  Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign an ID to the script ([which will explode in ancient browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html)), you can try:

```
var id = $("#idOfTheScript").parent()[0].id;
```