# Obtain a reference to <script> parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference

I have a similar problem like posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982598/obtaining-a-reference-do-the-scripts-parent-element) but instead of obtain the parent id, how Can I get a reference to the script parent without having to code an id for the script tag?

For example, I have the following code injected to a website:

```
<div>
     some other html tags
     <script src="http://path_to_my_script.js"></script>
</div>
```

What I need is that in my `path_to_my_script.js` file I can get a reference to the outer `div`.

There is a catch and is that the code will be copied&pasted in several places in the same webpage, which makes an identifier useless.

There is any chance to do that without to code an id in the entire code?

If the solution is with jQuery the better :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information/code

Comment: Do you want to avoid using id on the script tag to make sure older browsers don't blow up? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @Esailija: I updated the post, hope it help you to help me :D

Comment: @hradac: Thanks for the comment. Both of them. The firts reason is obvious, the other reason is that the code will be copied&pasted in several places in the same webpage, which makes an identifier useless.

Comment: @diosney You're using the same code copied and pasted throughout the same page? I would consider refactoring to reduce redundancy. Unfortunately without knowing what you're trying to do I can't make any recommendations.

Comment: @diosney look at Rob W's link. It's exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @RobW: +1 Awesome!!! Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!! :D. Please, Can you post your comment as an answser so I can accept it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As mentioned in [What is the current element in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210011/938089?what-is-the-current-element-in-javascript), the current `<script>` element is also the last `<script>` element, **at the time of execution**.

The answer also applies to your case, since the load of the external script is not deferred (through the `async` or `defer` attribute).

```
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
```

Most browsers (even IE6) support [`document.scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.scripts). Firefox supports this object as of version 9. So, the following code can also be used:

```
var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
```

Comment: How much I wanted this to be the solution to my problem it was not. The fact is that my application does a lot of dynamic loading of javascript but the `document.scripts` array does only contain the first and only javascript file that is actually in the html itself. All later loaded js-files are simply not there...

Comment: Easier: `document.currentScript.parentElement`

Comment: @user10898116 it seems this one is not supported by IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute selector to get a script with a specific `src`, then `parent('div')` to jump to its containing `div` element.

```
var parentDiv = $('script[src="path/to/script.js"]').parent('div');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answser. The script source attribute is  the same for all the code copied&pasted in the page. See comment to hradac. I will update the question to point this. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Well, obviously you're not going to be loading the same script multiple times in a single page, so you could simply build the pathname of the script dynamically into a variable and immediately inject it into the selector string.

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to refer your script by. How else do you expect to know which script you want? If you only have one script, you could always do

```
var myScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
```

to get a DOM element of the first script on your page. Or you could use jQuery and loop through your script to do something with each:

```
$("script").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```