# Accessing parent script tag from src Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
```

something.js:

```
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
```

This was recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312824/1099074.

However this solution doesn't work in certain cirumstances.

Same can be said of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3326554/1099074.

What would be an airtight solution that doesn't involve the frownable document.write? E.g. the solution I'm currently going with:

```
var childId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
document.write('<div id="' + childId + '"></div>');
var parentTag = document.getElementById(childId).parentNode;
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?!

Comment: I need to insert HTML using strictly Javascript directly below where the script tag that grabs the Javascript appears.

Comment: Why? What's the reason that you have to append something directly after the script tag? It could be in `<head>` for all you know. Also what are the _"certain circumstances"_ in which the current solution doesn't work?

Comment: Because it's an embed code for an ad. So whever the customer places the embed code, the <script> essentially inserts the ad there. The ad is embedded in the customer website.

Comment: We give them the <script> tag and they place it where they want the ad to be.

Comment: @Joe document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1] doesn't work. I am already using document.write, but from what I hear it is frownable.

Comment: In what circumstances doesn't `document.scripts[...]` work? I'm yet to encounter such a situation.

Comment: Can you explain under what circumstances your solution in `something.js` does not work? In this JSFiddle I use that + `appendChild` and it seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YC7TZ/

Comment: @Nit I'm not sure exactly, but it clearly isn't working sometimes in my test instance. I'm not sure exactly of the cause. It works most of the time however.

Comment: Find out replicable conditions under which it doesn't work and then work on solving the problem rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote in the past that accomplishes this. It does not assume that jquery exists, so it contains its own document-ready check. The trick is that it should wait until the document is loaded, *then* go back and add the element.

```
(function () {

    var current_script = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    current_script = current_script[current_script.length - 1];

    // modified from http://dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever
    function ready(callback) {
        /in/.test(document.readyState)
        ?setTimeout(function(){ready(callback)},9)
        :callback()
    }

    ready(function() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1));
        current_script.parentNode.insertBefore(div, current_script.nextSibling);
    });

})();
```

---

A simpler solution would be: Take control of the filename of your embeddable script. You could give the script a filename of `ad_embed_f4t4igjf8ig93.js`, and have the user embed that onto their page. On document-ready, just look for script tags with that src.

Comment: would this only work if there was only 1 script tag?

Comment: What if you match an id of an already existing element? Yes I like to nitpick, pun intended.

Comment: Yes this still works when there is only one script tag. As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/dxEcP/

Comment: I think you want to refer to `current_script` in your ready-callback, not just `script`, within the code example above.