# Change table cell css with inner script without relying on id, class, or contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent

I am using an ASP.NET MVC helper method to create a webgrid. I want to dynamically set the colors of a table row but I have no access to the td tag to change its properties or add an id.

So what I am trying to do from the backend is inject a script in the td's body to conditionally change its color. I have tried:

```
<script>$(this).css("background-color", "red !important");</script>
```

and this did not work. If this didn't work then I am not sure what else I can do as this seemed like the most direct approach; although I am a novice with javascript so I am looking for some help on this.

I have found other topic questions similar to what I am asking but the responses seems to mostly use contains, onclick, or make use of an id tag.

Basically if this was pure markup, and you had a table,

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       how to insert a script here to change this current elements color
       without know its id?
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element

Comment: you cant use `this` because `this` is a reference to the member that invokes the **current function** and you dont have **current function** so this script is invalid, try with another selector ( tag name, class or id....) **or** try with pure css `td{background-color: red !important}`

Comment: The problem is this is a dynamic build so I only want certain cells colored. The helper method will determine the other colors from the server side and build it and send to client. If I do td{... it will change every td.

Comment: Whoever gave the downvote, it would be nice to let me know why you downvoted so maybe I can better the question.

Comment: Martin, no one is clicking anything on my tables. So that question nor its response will work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allTD = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
</script>
```

Wich will return a collection of **all** the `td` elements in your `HTML` file.

Then, all you have to do is to iterate over the collection and change the style of the elements.

More info at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: I am already iterating over the table on the back end and trying to avoid redundancy but iterating over it again. 

The helper method builds the table using C# objects the only thing I can do is conditionally check an object and add data to the inside of the td body, so I was trying to manipulate it from inside and I thought maybe there was a good way through javascript to grab a hold of that td element from the body without using an id, or classname.

Comment: Then it is impossible to do without having an user intervention on the element that have to be changed.
If you can add data in the `td`, I assume that you have some acces to that `td` so you can add a `style` attribute to the `td` node and put there the CSS you want.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to manipulate it by inserting an input field, hiding it, and and setting its value to the color I wanted. Then made a call to it, and getting parent() and was able to do it that way. I thought maybe there was some build in way with JavaScript as I am not very experienced with JavaScript.