# javascript only, is there a way to get span that script is contained in

Tags: javascript

I know you can do something like closest in jQuery, but I don't have that luxury here. I'm trying to obtain the span elements without a span id or class?

```
<table>
<tr><td><span><script>document.getElementById('The span I am in');</script></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span><script>document.getElementById('The span I am in');</script></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think script elements have a perception of what element they're inside...

Comment: put an id on the span

Comment: Marking a question a duplicate with another question that's a duplicate. _Duplicatception_

Comment: @KyleRichardson, i'm sorry i misprinted...without id or class

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to bypass the duplicate and link to first question?

Comment: You can get the first element of the element and check if it is a script tag or not:

    `function HasScript(element)
    {
       if(element.children[0].tagName == 'script')
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }` and if the script is not the first child, check all children by a for loop

Comment: @JCOC611: If there's useful information, then what's the difference? And marking it as a dupe of another dupe gives a series of links that are easily followed and not available by linking to the end duplicate.

Comment: The question isn't unclear at all. The pseudo-code makes it very clear what the goal is. The [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element)  covers that.

Comment: The [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element) question is specifically about getting the parent element of the script, which is what this question is trying to do. While that question has been closed as a duplicate, the [target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) for it is one that is about getting the script, not the script's parent, so it isn't as close a duplicate.