# Google Tag Manager: Delete custom HTML blocks after each pageview?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We have a single-page-application with Google Tag Manager setup, and a working usage of the custom HTML fragment for a tracking library to fire a JS method for every page view. Though it works - it leaves behind HTML script fragments for each page view.

**My question:** Is there some existing functionality that will delete the Custom HTML blocks?

Or should would I have to write custom code in the same script to clear up old versions of the same snippet?

Custom HTML snippet for per-page tracking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  someTrackingLibrary.pageViewEvent();
</script>
```

Note: The use of the custom script block is from some advice given to us, and kinda mentioned in [this GTM documentation](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#4-custom-javascript):

> The third, unwritten rule is that the function should only return a
>   value. You shouldn’t use a Custom JavaScript variable to modify the
>   global namescape by pushing values to dataLayer for example. If you
>   want to tamper with global variables from a function, it’s better to
>   create a Custom HTML tag for this purpose.

And is suggested to not be done with a variable:

> Variables must never have side effects
>
> Remember how variables should only be used to return values? Well,
>   sometimes you might be tempted to use a variable to change the state
>   of the global object or to set or push stuff into dataLayer. Don’t do
>   it! Because variables can be resolved in multiple ways, and not just
>   in tags as you’d expect, you might find yourself creating infinite
>   loops, pushing stuff into dataLayer multiple times, or severely
>   hurting page performance.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- **Do not use variables to make create/delete operations**: you do not control when variables are executed (you can create a dummy JS variable with console output, you'll be surprised how often and seemingly randomly it is called), thus using variables for modifying operations is a very bad idea
- **There is no built-in GTM functionality** to achieve what you want
- **You can create a custom tag to do it**: see below example. The code logic is that at the time of its execution, [a `<script>` block is the last script available in the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element) (logically since the browser just parsed it), therefore it's pretty easy to retrieve it. You could add a `dataLayer.push` call at the end of your script blocks to to notify GTM that the script has been executed.

> If you try to implementing a solution without the `dataLayer.push`
>   method, you'll have a race condition with the risk of GTM deleting the
>   script tags before they have been executed (since GTM is loading async
>   and might be ready before browser parses those script blocks).

Below is the sample page code:

```
<script>
    var removeBlock = function() {
        var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: "delete_block",
            block: scriptTag
        });
    }
</script>
<script id="block1">
    console.log("block1");
</script>
<script id="block2" type="text/javascript">
    // YOUR ANALYTICS CODE HERE BEFORE GTM PUSH
    console.log("block2");
    removeBlock();
</script>
<script id="block3">
    console.log("block3");
</script>
```

[image]

Then create a trigger based on `event=delete_block` and here is the GTM `Custom HTML` tag code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var block = {{block}}; // GTM dataLayer variable "block"
  block.parentNode.removeChild(block);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Is there some existing functionality that will delete the Custom HTML blocks?**

No. GTM is a tag manager, you need to write your custom code to delete the code blocks.

I would suggest you doing it via your 3rd party library if that has some functionality to do so. Else you can write custom JS or add a tag like wise.

Answer (score 1):

As a belated answer, do not use custom HTML tags anymore - for most intents and purposes, they have been superseded by [custom templates](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates).

Custom templates allow to define an UI (e.g. to specify account ids or whatever input is necessary for your tag) and a code block. The only issue (and that's a good issue, even if it's annoying sometimes) is that you are limited to what Google calls "sandboxed javascript". I.e. you can not use all features of standard JS, you have to go through APIS provided by Google - a "good issue" because it offers extra levels of security, however some things (that are insecure by nature) do not work with sandboxed Javascript (e.g. no modifying the prototype chain for objects, no direct DOM access and some other limitations).

However they avoid the problem of overpopulating the DOM with copies of your custom tag (and for your example, you can [call functions that are defined on the global namespace](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#callinwindow)).