# How to get the parent element of a map

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to hand over the id of the div in the following code. Is it possible to get the id of the parent element in the JavaScript function?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/Leaflet/leaflet.css" >
<script src="../js/Leaflet/leaflet.js" ></script>
<script>
'use strict';
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

function show_karte(div_id, mittelpunkt, zoom){
var osmLayer = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 20, attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'});
var mittelpunkt = [mittelpunkt[1], mittelpunkt[0]]
var map = L.map(div_id,{layers: [osmLayer]}).setView(mittelpunkt, zoom};    
</script>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width:450px; height: 450px;">
    <script  type="text/javascript"> show_karte("map",[6.026173,50.816022],13); </script>
</div>
<div id="xyz"><p> some text </p></div>
<div id="map1" style="width:550px; height: 450px;">
    <script  type="text/javascript"> show_karte("map1",[6.10428,50.76079],11); </script>
</div>
<div id="map2" style="width:650px; height:450px">  
    <script  type="text/javascript">show_karte("map2",[6.10428,50.76079],12); </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a "map" in this case? Are you looking for the div around the script, or the div around the divs with IDs like `map1`? You might simplify your markup to make that more clear. You could also remove irrelevant bits like the inline styles, stylesheet links, etc. Just show what's related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not generate the map in that fashion but loop through `map` classes and pull data from attributes. Below I added a class of `map` to each div, then I added the latitude, longitude and zoom as data attributes. Then simply loop through them and pull the data as needed.

```js
function  show_karte(id, pos, zoom){
console.log(id,pos,zoom);
}

var maps = document.getElementsByClassName("map");

for(var x = 0;x < maps.length;x++){
    let this_map = maps[x];
    
    show_karte(this_map.getAttribute('id'),[this_map.getAttribute('data-lat'),this_map.getAttribute('data-lon')],this_map.getAttribute('data-zoom'));
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="map" data-zoom="13" data-lat="6.026173" data-lon="50.816022" style="width:450px; height: 450px;"></div>

<div id="xyz"><p> some text </p></div>

<div id="map1" class="map" data-zoom="11" data-lat="6.10428" data-lon="50.76079" style="width:550px; height: 450px;"></div>

<div id="map2" class="map" data-zoom="12" data-lat="6.10428" data-lon="50.76079" style="width:650px; height:450px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to search actual script element (maybe div is enough in your case), from it's parent you can read your id.

[Obtain a reference to <script> parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element)

```js
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
var parentDiv = scriptTag.parentNode;
var mapId = parentDiv.id;
```

Comment: That is just the solution I'm looking for, thanks. It seems simplier than the solution of imvain2. But I don't understand the second line of your code. In the first line "scriptTag" is an array, right? For this array in my example scriptTag.length delivers 4,7,8 calling show_karte tree times!?? But your code in the beginning of my function show_karte works well.

Comment: Also maybe look at what is in "this" maybe you do not need to search in the document.

Comment: Also on stackoverflow, you accept the solution by clicking on tick icon...

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow is such a huge, complicated system for a new dummy. I didn't find, what's the "tick ikon". Maybe I did so. - alert (this) in my function delivers the window object, this does not help me.