# How do I load an external javascript function in an html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `sample.js` file which contains

```
document.write('<script>........</script><a>...</a><style>....</style>');
```

And I have this script `<script src="https://example.com/sample.js"></script>` in external website. Where-ever I use this script, `sample.js` is loaded immediately. And all other elements are not removed even though I use `document.write`

I want to load the above script in multiple Html `<div>` or other elements, where we define something like `id="example"` or `class="example"` or `data-sample-js`

So how do I modify the `sample.js` file to achieve this.

So far, I have tried in the `sample.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
document.querySelectorAll("[data-sample-js]").forEach(elem => {
 elem.innerHTML = document.write('<script>...</script><a>...</a><style>...</style>');
});});
```

So where-ever we place the `<script src="https://example.com/sample.js"></script>` along with `<div data-sample-js></div>` the javascript is loaded but it will remove all other html elements in the page.

EDIT:

```
There is a full html document is placed in the document.write(). 
It can have multiple scripts, styles, metas and all other possible codes.
that will be present in a static html webpage, including <script src="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to work out exactly what you mean. From what I can infer, you would like the code in `sample.js` to be applied to all elements that have a specific characteristic rather than purely executing the code.

For this you'll want to use the likes of element selectors e.g.

```
document.getElementByClassName(string);
document.getElementByTagName(string);
document.querySelectorAll(string);
```

More can be found here.

https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/

An example of using these would be:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-sample-js]").forEach(elem => {
    elem.innerText += "This is a sample text";
});
```

```html
<div data-sample-js>Test</div>
```

Which will concatenate `This is a sample text` onto the content of any element with `data-sample-js` as an attribute.

Note that this code must be imported at the end to ensure that all elements are added to the DOM and loaded before the script takes place.

EDIT 1:

As mentioned in these comments, do not use `document.write` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Instead, I recommend using a different method for loading this content. Stylesheets can be added by simply adding the `<style>` to the head of the page and for scripts use a dynamic loader. More information on `<script>` imports can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously).

EDIT 2:

It appears you are trying to write frontend JavaScript code to dynamically generate a page. You should not do this and instead take care of this in the backend application that serves the page. This is fairly simple in most backend languages / frameworks (PHP can simply use [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)).

Comment: This works good. But is there a way, that it will work when the script is placed anywhere on the page

Comment: The script could be imported anywhere but make sure it’s wrapped in an onload to ensure that the page is fully loaded before it performs the actions

Comment: I am just asking, if it possible to add js file on top instead on below. Since i use document.write all html codes already present on the page will get removed when i use window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')

Comment: Generally speaking, do not use document.write. It's very bad practice so try to use something such as `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` for editing the content of the elements on your page. See this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice. It isn't required that you put this at the bottom of your script or perform an onload but it is advised

Comment: I have used the `document.write` since it contains `script` and `style` elements.

Comment: Script and style elements can be dynamically created without the use of `document.write`. Take a look into this for scripts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously and you can use `document.createElement` for styles I believe (or just adding styles using `document.head.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202473/discussion-between-dfgdfh-and-hive7).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element) is what you trying to achieve.

Long story short:

```js
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
parentTag.innerHTML = 'This is a sample text to replace its content';
parentTag.classList.add('new_class');
parentTag.id = 'new_id';
```