# Get HTML tag in where Javascript is included

Tags: javascript, html

Here is some HTML:

```
<div>
     hello text
     <script src="/javascript.js" ></script>
</div>
```

and in javascript.js, I want to get the height and width of the the div where javascript.js is included.

I found how you could do it with ID:

```
document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
```

but how to reference it to that div where javascript.js is included?

Comment: You can't because the element has not been rendered yet at that point. The best you can do is to postpone the calculation to when the DOM has already loaded.

Comment: you can add a class or id to your `div` like `script-div` then get div attrs..

Comment: I think this post may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299846/obtain-a-reference-to-script-parent-element , or maybe this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982598/obtaining-a-reference-do-the-scripts-parent-element

Comment: @Bartdude: Those are actually duplicates. You should flag the question as such if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: @Felix I must admit I don't know how to do so...

Comment: @Bartdude: There should be a `flag` link at the end of the question (next to `share` and `edit`). And one of the (sub-)reasons should include to flag it as duplicate I believe.

Comment: @Felix : Indeed ! I didn't dare to use it as I was affraid it would immediately perform like a "report abuse" action... Thanks for making me a better SO user :-)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot refer to the div in the javascript.js file directly. however, you can get the div ID on document load and sctore it in some global variable for future use.

```
 var myDiv = []  
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('script').each(function(){
        myDiv.push($(this).parent('div'))        
      })
 } )
```